# Data on charging station for electrical cars

Tags: geospatial

I am currently looking for data sets on charging stations for electrical-powered cars in Berlin, Germany. I checked the Berliner Senat Website but found only this http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/berlin/service.jsp?id=re_ausbau_der_ladeinfrastruktur@senstadt&type=WFS&themeType=spatial
While this is interesting, it contains only information about charging stations in different states of planning and authorization, but not actually stations where one could charge a vehicle.
Where could I find data on electrical charging stations in Berlin for import in GIS software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could query OpenStreetMap with amenity `charging_station`.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity=charging_station

For example, you could use the Overpass API: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/zBb.

Run the query and click "export" to download the data.

[image]
[image]