# Seeking EV charging station data for Denmark

Tags: geospatial, transportation

Does anyone have a link to some open source data on EV charging station data preferably in Denmark, but maybe Europe?

Comment: Related, or duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/12961/1511

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data on charging station for electrical cars](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12961/data-on-charging-station-for-electrical-cars)